# How to make my button hover transition smooth?

Tags: css

I created an image button that shows 2 different images on mouse over.

My problem is that it flickrs when hovered. How do I do it so that when its hovered, the transition is smooth.

This is what my current code looks like:

```
<style>
.test{
width:620px;
height:55px;
background: url(1.jpg);
text-indent: -9999px
}

.test:hover{
background: url(2.jpg);
cursor: hand;
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<p class="test"><a href="#">TEST ONLY</a>
```

Below the live demo that shows the problem:

http://magestimate.com/csstest/

Comment: This has been covered so many times on SO and countless other blogs, try to Google it before you ask here :) Well asked question though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with 2.jpg not being loaded yet and the server isn't that quick.

Try adding this to your HTML

```
<img src="2.jpg" alt="" style="display:none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you only want to make sure that the images does not load on demand then simply add a preloader for all the images...

You will have to add this in the body tag..

ex.

> ```
> <body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/x.png' 'images/y.png')">
>
> </body>
> ```

and so forth.

**Awesome Andre** out!!

http://www.awesomeandre.tk